# Possible to write MySQL stored procedures in ruby?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have heard that one in PostgreSQL could write stored procedures in ruby (also python/java/c++).

Is this possible in MySQL?

Because I dont want to learn their own language for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Just install PostgreSQL on your (virtual) system and install PL/Ruby as well:
http://moulon.inra.fr/ruby/plruby.html

Setting up a virtual machine (in VMware or Virtual Box) using Ubuntu with PostgreSQL, takes just a few minutes:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postgresql.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply put - nope.  In MySQL you have to write a SP in their language or a UDF in [C/C++](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html). I brought up a C/C++ UDF, but I don't believe you can even really do a stored procedure in them.

They don't support different languages via a pluggable system like PostgreSQL.